# Can one write/convert a long Excel formula as a function, using only Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, text-formatting

I want to make, in MS Excel, an equivalent of the MS Word *Sentence case*, to often be able to convert Excel text strings from all-caps to sentence case (without having to teach myself VBA).

My one-parameter formula to do this is =(LEFT(B3) & MID(LOWER(B3),2,LEN(LOWER(B3)))).

(I have seen [Using Excel sheet as a function](https://superuser.com/questions/185382/using-excel-sheet-as-a-function) but that isn't quite what I'm seeking.)

Can I make a function that would allow me to simply reference the cell holding the all-caps string, e.g. =Sentence(B3) ?

Thank you for your thoughts/advice

Comment: =(UPPER(LEFT(B3)) & LOWER(MID(B3,2,LEN(B3))))

Comment: Thank you - I do know how to do that, Prem; my own formula is similar to yours. I'm looking for a way to be able to type something *much* shorter, e.g. =Sentence(cell ref), or even =Sent(ref)  rather than the whole long formula.

Comment: No, passing a parameter to a user-defined function is only possible using a programming language. However, you can insert this long expression into a "named range" - select cell C3, press CTRL+F3, add a new range, give a name (for example, **Sent**) and the `=UPPER(LEFT(B3;1)) & LOWER(MID(B3;2;LEN(B3)))` formula. Now, wherever you write `=Sent`, the cell will work for the text from the cell on the left (as if you were calling `Sent` with the `RC[-1]` parameter)

Comment: @JohnSUN Many thanks - will give that a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If you are an Excel O365 subscriber***, the LAMBDA() function is designed specifically to do *exactly* what you are attempting.

You would go into Name Manager and create a name `Sentence`.  In the "Refers to" field you would enter:

`=Lambda(a, LEFT(a) & MID(LOWER(a),2,LEN(LOWER(a))))`

I'd personally simplify this to just:

`=Lambda(a, LEFT(a) & LOWER(RIGHT(a,LEN(a)-1)))`

In either case, `=Sentence(B3)` would deliver exactly the result you're seeking.  But--this does require the newer functionality of O365 Excel.  Your alternative if you are not an O365 customer is to define a macro, but that has implications that may be undesirable to your use case.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Fortunately, I have recently become an O365 subscriber. Many thanks, Max.

Comment: @iSeeker I modified my answer a bit.  `LEN(LOWER(a))` should be identical in value to `LEN(a)`, which eliminates an unnecessary function call.  And I just used RIGHT() instead MID() in my second example.  O365 has a whole range of functions that are life-changing if you are a frequent Excel user.  I cannot overstate the impact of the changes.

Comment: @Max_R Thanks for that and for alerting me to  https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-365-new-functions.htm Excel , Max.

Comment: @Max_R I added a right parenthesis to my copy of your simplified formula, then worked perfectly.

Comment: @iSeeker Thanks, I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

`=(LEFT(B3) & MID(LOWER(B3),2,LEN(LOWER(B3))))`
in shorter form for ALL Excel-varints/versions
`=LEFT(B3,1) & LOWER(MID(B3,2,1000))`

- The second parameter to LEFT() is mandatory.
- The last (third) parameter to MID() may be any excessive number to keep as my characters from the string as available
  *(curiosity fact, LibreOffice: `POWER(2,31)-2` works, `POWER(2,31)-1` does not)*.
- The use of LOWER() is only necessary once.

Comment: Yes, that works too, with LAMBDA. Thanks